# Wrong Answer python3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

> You are given a set S and Q queries. Initially, S is empty. In each query:
>
> You are given a positive integer X.
> You should insert X into S.
> For each y∈S before this query such that y≠X, you should also insert y⊕X into S (⊕ denotes the XOR operation).
> Then, you should find two values E and O: the number of elements of S with an even number of 1's and with an odd number of 1's in the binary representation, respectively.

I have tried splitting the problem into smaller subproblems but it seems to exceed time because of large input size and large list size. Any suggestion into the code and further optimization will be very helpful.I have mow used set but the expected output is not as same as my output. Any suggestions as where I am going wrong in the solution code..?

```
s=set()
def fun(n,q):
    c=0
    cc=0
    s.add(n)
    for k in range(len(list(s))):
        if list(s)[k]!=n:
            s.add((list(s)[k])^n)
            
    for k in s:
        if bin(k)[2::].count('1')%2==0:
            c+=1
        else:
            cc+=1
    print(c,cc)
    
    
for _ in range(int(input())):
    q=int(input())
    for j in range(q):
        n=int(input())
        fun(n,q)
```

Example Input:

```
1
3
4
2
7
```

Example Output:

```
0 1
1 2
3 4
```

Comment: The description is not clear for me: You said X must be inserted to S. Then iterate over each value S different than X, but in your for loop, the else statement is executed when the value is actually X and you calculate E and O

Comment: the code has been edited and the description is same as what asked in question

Answer (score 0):

The first thing i see wrong on your code is that S should be a set of numbers. A list can have duplicates, so you need to work with [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) 
 
And to optimize your script, you can start by improving how you count the amount of enabled bits in your number expressed in binary. Such count is called the [hamming weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight#Efficient_implementation) of a string. 

Search it on the web. For instance you have [this article](https://www.expobrain.net/2013/07/29/hamming-weights-python-implementation/)

Comment: Yes..I know I could have used set but set has a problem of assignment thus I preferred using list with an if condition that checks for duplicates values

Comment: I know sets have no duplicates values ....but you go and read the doc for item assignment in set ...We can not assign values to set that is why I used list instead of set with an if condition to check and discard duplicate values

Comment: In which part of your code you are assigning values to S?

Comment: I removed it because it was giving error message like "Item assignment is not valid for set"

Comment: If you still want to work with lists, one way yo remove duplicates is to convert it to set and then back to list. But that is very inneficient

Comment: And you got item assigment error because you do something like S[k] = ... You only need to use methods put and discard to add/remove values

Answer (score 0):

I think you are inserting duplicate value in your List. fix it you will be good to go.

Solution And Reference :- https://whitefox-89ea6.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: I am using set ,which never takes duplicate values into it.